# Issues with requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to read a news webpage to get the titles of their stories. I'm attempting to put them in a list, but I keep getting an empty list. Can someone please point in the right direction here? What am I missing? Please see code below. Thanks.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://nypost.com/'
ttl_lst = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")

title = soup.findAll('h2', {'class': 'story-heading'})

for row in title:
     ttl_lst.append(row.text)

print (ttl_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

the requests module only returns the first html file sent to them. Sites like nypost use ajax requests to get their articles. You will have to use something like selenium for this, which allows for ajax requests after the page loads.

Comment: Thanks. Will try selenium